# Way to implement SSO for web and desktop applications

Tags: single-sign-on, kerberos, saml

I am reading alot about federated identity management and technologies like SAML, which can be used for implementing SSO for web applications, and Kerberos, which can be used for implementing SSO für desktop applications.

This is how I understood it so far. If we have the case, that we want to have SSO for a set of web applications and desktop applications, what are the technologies that are available for that? Do I have to combine SAML and Kerberos or is there another technology that fits better?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Microsoft ADFS and Oracle Access Manager are SSO products which supports SAML, Kerberos and other related protocols, does Windows based authentication and thus provide SSO access across webapps and desktop.

Check,
http://blogs.technet.com/b/abizerh/archive/2013/04/11/more-information-about-sso-experience-when-authenticating-via-adfs.aspx

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e15740/wna.htm